# Open URL in iframe (on parent) from popup opened from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I know the title can be confusing but I have got a jsp page which has got an iframe. There are couple of links on this iframe which launches a popup window. On the pop up window, user can do a search on the departments and when the user selects any department from the search result, the form is submitted and it should use the selected department top open the next page on the iframe.

The form submission is causing the new page to be displayed on the parent page rather than in the iframe on parent page.

Here is the code on the pop up jsp which gets executed once the search result is selected-

```
document.pform.action = "some URL";
document.pform.target="target";

document.pform.submit();

opener.focus();
```

Comment: you appear to be submitting a form, I don't see a popup or an iframe? Basically I don't get the question?

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the issue was with the action, it was pointing to the parent page instead of the frame causing the new page to open in the parent window.Fixing the action in 
document.pform.action = "some URL";

solved the issue.